# Unable to Deploy war using maven 3.x

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to deploy my web-application to tomcat using maven 3.x here is the snap shot of the pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoapp</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Blank Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.2.3</struts2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>localhost</server>
                <path>/WebApp</path>

        </configuration>
</plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i tried the following goal in maven `mvn deploy` but i got the following build fail with following error

```
 Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

after doing some googling i added the following entry to my pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>myRepoId</id>
      <name>myCompanyReporsitory</name>
      <!-- <url>scp://nothing/</url>

      <url>${user.home}/m2/repository</url> -->
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

but i am not sure what should be the URL since using `${user.home}/m2/repository` gave another error with build failure

```
Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository myRepoId (C:\Users\admin/m2/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: using `mvn tomcat:deploye` did what i was asking from Maven.

Comment: Is that the solution to your issue? You should answer and accept yourself, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mvn deploy` tries to send the result of the package goal to the url of repository described in your POM.
I aims not at deploying a Web application on its server but to share the library produced with other.

If what you need is to deploy you webapp, then the tomcat plugin is a solution.

BTW: The connector issue when trying to deploy is due to the fact that to enable SCP you need to add the `wagon-scp` connector.